# Default skybox missing in new scene

Tags: unity, 3d, c, skybox

Now on my existing project, if I **create a new scene**, my game view looks like this:

[image: Grey cube on solid blue background]

The game view has a solid colour background, instead of a 3D-looking skybox. I'm expecting something like below (my old existing scene):

[image: Purple cube with default Unity skybox]

How can I get my skybox back in new scenes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Is the issue that what you see in the game isn't what you see in the editor window? If so, more information is required (i.e. screenshots showing the unity editor too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out your lighting settings and the skybox (which you can find inside the lighting settings).

It seems like your new scene doesn't have one anymore. Normally it should have. Are you sure you haven't changed the lighting settings?

[See the Unity documentation on the Skybox component for reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Skybox.html)

Comment: yes correct, now 3d environment appear by choose skybox material & light material..thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you set your project's default mode to 2D instead of 3D.

In 3D mode, new scenes are generated with a skybox (which draws the banding of colours in the background), a perspective camera, and a directional light.

In 2D, new scenes are generated with just an orthographic camera by default.

You can still add the other content yourself (2D/3D mode isn't a hard wall, just some convenient starting values for different kinds of projects)

You can change this default setting under:

```
Edit > Project Settings > Editor > "Default Behaviour Mode"
```

Or [read more about 2D & 3D settings and what they affect in the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/2DAnd3DModeSettings.html).

---

Another possible cause is if the "Clear Flags" on your camera are set to "Solid Colour" instead of "Skybox" - in that case, the camera just draws a flat colour (default greyish blue) into the background instead of the gradient or image coming from the skybox in your lighting settings.

Comment: i have try change this, but not effect, any idea ?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What did you try to change?